# Wait for condition before continuing method

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, cocoa

I'm writing a class which retrieves and parses a file downloaded from a server.

I have a method inside the class which parses the information, and the information is downloaded when the class is initialized.

The problem is, sometimes, the method that parses the information is called before the information itself is downloaded.

```
FileParser *instance = [[FileParser alloc] initWithURL:@"somewhere"];
[instance parseData];
```

Every time the `parseData` method is called directly after the class is initialized, it fails because not all of the content is available.

How can I wait until all the information is downloaded before I continue executing the parseData method, without interrupting the main thread?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at [`NSOperation`](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&tbo=d&spell=1&q=nsoperationqueue+examples&sa=X&ei=Lmz2ULOODcjLsgb104GIDA&ved=0CC4QBSgA&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=65fe59e85b7b1b3b&biw=1505&bih=867&ion=1). It basically allows you to have several operations executing in a background queue and also supports operation dependency.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you should think about using delegates.
You pass your dowloading class a delegate that will handle the downloaded data.
See [here](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-custom-delegates/)

Answer (score 0):

Simple: You need to either perform this entire operation on a background thread/queue, or refactor your `FileParser` class towards a more asynchronous design. That design would be centered around a callback mechanism, such as delegation or blocks.